# How do I make DropdownButtonFormField show me the output that is the value that I have saved in my database

Tags: flutter

I am working with a DropdownButtonFormField and so far the list is loading me, but I would like you to load the list and also load the item that is saved in my database and show it to me as output indicating that the user had already selected an item previously.

This is the code that I am using

```
                               DropdownButtonFormField(
                                isDense: true,
                                //hint: new Text("Seleccione Barrio"),
                                items: dataBarrio.map((item) {
                                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                    child: new Text(item['nom']),
                                    value: item['id'].toString(),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (newVal) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _mySelectionBarrio = newVal;
                                  });
                                },
                                value: _mySelectionBarrio,
                              )
```

Comment: Have you looked into the "initialValue" prop for the DropdownButtonFormField? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html

Comment: I try to use it and it marks error

Comment: You need to make sure the initial value is equal to the item in the list, so you might need to set the DropdownMenuItem's to be comparable or you can create the list before hand and then set the initial value equal to an item in the list you created.